# (What's [object Object] ERROR)Using Dropzone.js with laravel5.5

Tags: php, laravel, drag-and-drop, laravel-5.5, dropzone.js

I was following [this site](https://medium.com/@AhmadYousefDev/multiple-image-uploader-with-laravel-5-5-and-dropzone-js-6f39974ba1c6) to use dropzone to upload multiple images with laravel5.5. But it doesn`t work.

When I upload .jpg file an error occurs. For example,

```
[object Object]
```

I want to know how to solve this. So, please give me some tips.

**UploadController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request){

        $time = Carbon::now();

        $image = $request->file('file');

        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $directory = date_format($time, 'Y') . '/' . date_format($time, 'm');

        $filename = str_random(5).date_format($time,'d').rand(1,9).date_format($time,'h').".".$extension;

        $upload_success = $image->storeAs($directory, $filename, 'public');

        if ($upload_success) {
            return response()->json($upload_success, 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('error', 400);
        }
    }
}
```

**filesystem.php**

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('uploads'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/upload' , 'UploadController@upload');
Route::get('/test', function () {
return view('uptest');});
```

**uptest.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html><html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="{{url('js/dropzone.js')}}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/dropzone.css')}}">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <script>
            Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                paramName: 'file',
                maxFilesize: 20, // MB
                maxFiles: 25,
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",

            };
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{{ url('/upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Those are which I make at localhost.

Comment: `[object Object]` is not an error, its the to string cast of an `Object`. Where does this get logged?

Comment: It appears above the image. And on Developer Tools,it says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).Please give me how to solve.

Comment: Are you using Linux? Check your permissions. maybe writing is not enabled.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu18.04. Which file or directory should I check?

Comment: "dropzone.js:2782" causes the error of "POST http://localhost:8000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)".     Code is like this  =>    value: function submitRequest(xhr, formData, files) {
      xhr.send(formData);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting upload sizes from the **dropzone config** to **virtual host** to **php.ini**